# JNI undefined reference to functions

Tags: c, makefile, java-native-interface, mingw

I've got a JNI setup in C with one C file with the code and one java class to call the C code. Whenever I call a function inside another function in my C code I get an error when compiling the makefile:

```
   CCode.o:CCode.c:(.text+0x205): undefined reference to `CFunction'
   collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
   make: *** [CCode.dll] Error 1
```

Using MinGW to compile in eclipse. All functions apart from the functions that call others work as intended.

```
# Define a variable for classpath
CLASS_PATH = ../bin
# Define a virtual path for .class in the bin directory
vpath %.class $(CLASS_PATH)

all : CCode.dll

# $@ matches the target, $< matches the first dependancy
CCode.dll : CCode.o
gcc -Wl,--add-stdcall-alias -shared -o $@ $<

# $@ matches the target, $< matches the first dependancy
CCode.o : CCode.c CCode.h
gcc -I "<<jdk location>>" -I "<<jdk location>>" -c $< -o $@

# $* matches the target filename without the extension
CCode.h : CCode.class
javah -classpath $(CLASS_PATH) $*

clean :
    rm CCode.h CCode.o CCode.dll
```

Comment: What reason do you have to think that function `CFunction()` is, in fact, available to the native library?  This is where the [mcve] comes in.

Comment: I included the makefile, I believe the problem to be within that file.

Comment: I not only believe but have full confidence that adding a Makefile to what you already presented does not come close to making it a [mcve].

Comment: most likely, there is a typo in your C code

Comment: @DSingh *I included the makefile, I believe the problem to be within that file.*  What do you base that belief on?

Comment: @AndrewHenle well I only have 3 files for this program, the Java class that just contains simple calls to the native functions, the C code which contains the 2 very basic functions and the makefile. I don't see how I could have a problem with the C code.

Comment: You have to add the library that `CFunction` is in to your linker call. Search the *net for "undefined reference" to find lots of explanations.